# Removed ZFS files reoccurring after remount

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, zfs, zfsonlinux

I have a nasty situation with some of my ZFS filesystems (see list below). Files I removed therein keep reappearing after a remount (such after a reboot). One such filesystem is `/root`. I get an mount error because the `/root` directory is not empty. Fair enough, I do a `rm -rf /root` and then a `zfs mount vol/HOME/root`. Everything is fine until the next reboot, when I get the same error again, because the whole directory is in the same state as before the previous mount.

I have the same problem with `/var` which was so bad, I left it in the / directory without its own filesystem.

By the same logic, I should have the same problems with `/home` or `/tmp`. But I don't.

A scrub did not find any errors. What kind of effect is this and how can I correct the situation?

```
zfs list

NAME                               USED  AVAIL  REFER  MOUNTPOINT
vol                                310G  1.10T   198K  none
vol/GENTOO                        9.72G  1.10T   198K  none
vol/GENTOO/usr-portage            1.25G  1.10T  1.25G  /usr/portage
vol/GENTOO/usr-portage-distfiles  8.47G  1.10T  8.47G  /usr/portage/distfiles
vol/GENTOO/usr-portage-packages    151K  1.10T   151K  /usr/portage/packages
vol/HOME                          20.0G  1.10T  20.0G  /home
vol/HOME/root                     17.6M  1.10T  17.6M  /root
vol/ROOT                           279G  1.10T   198K  none
vol/ROOT/gentoo                    279G  1.10T   279G  /
vol/TMP                            562M  1.10T   562M  /tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

ZFS root is often a bad idea... but maybe you can `chatter +i /` (when the filesystem is unmounted) to prevent writing to the empty mountpoint.

See: [Prevent the possiblity of writing data to an unmounted mount point directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/570255/prevent-the-possiblity-of-writing-data-to-an-unmounted-mount-point-directory/570271#570271)

Comment: Why is ZFS root bad?

Answer (score 0):

I second @eewhite in saying ZFS root is not a good idea.
Anyway, try setting **`xattr=sa`** on your ZFS filesystem and, after remounting it, check if something changed.

Also have a look [here](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/1548): it can be related to your problem, perhaps.